# TableView, TableColumns vanish off the right edge when resizing

Tags: javafx-8

Using some custom resizing behaviour I'm losing columns off the right side of the TableView. I have to use `UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` (or maybe write a custom POLICY) so that I can size some of the columns to their content.

I have some custom behaviour for the resizing of columns in the TableViews I use in my application. 
I use the reflection pattern to autoresize some columns to their content when the data first populates. The remaining columns width is set to a proportion of the remaining width (if there are 3 columns not being autoresized then remaining width/3=column width).

I also have a column width listener which will listen for when a user drags column widths or double clicks on the header divider to size the column to it's content. I also listen to the width of the table itself and then assign any new extra width to the last column.
The above works ok but the issue is when a user resizes a column or multiple columns to the point the last column is as small as it can go columns will start to getting pushed off the right side of the TableView. It makes sense it would do this as I have my POLICY set to UNCONSTRAINED. I obviously can't use `CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` or the above logic won't work.

Is there a custom policy out there that will reduce the rightmost columns inside 1 by 1 as the user increases the column width, so the right column first until it's as small as it can be, then the next rightmost and so on. Or do I need to write this behaviour? I did come across a Koitlin based POLICY in TorpedoFX that looked interesting but I'd rather stay pure Java.

Basically the outcome I want is what I have now but any user resizing just reduces the right-most column to a minimum size, then the next right-most and so on until all the columns to the right of the column the user is resizing are at minimum size but are still visible on the TableView. If there are no columns to the right that can be resized then the user shouldn't be able to resize their column without first resizing a column to the left. 
Columns should never disappear off the right side of the TableView.
I've written a test class that mimics this behaviour, it's slightly verbose in places and would be refactored in the real application.

```java
package application;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumnBase;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private TableView<TableData> table = new TableView<TableData>();
    private ObservableList<TableData> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private boolean columnResizeOperationPerformed = false;
    private String resizeThreeColumn = "";
    private String resizeFourColumn = "";
    private String resizeSixColumn = "";
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setWidth(1300);
        stage.setHeight(600);

        TableColumn<TableData, String> oneColumn = new TableColumn<>("One");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> twoColumn = new TableColumn<>("Two");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> threeColumn = new TableColumn<>("Three");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> fourColumn = new TableColumn<>("Four");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> fiveColumn = new TableColumn<>("Five");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> sixColumn = new TableColumn<>("Six");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> sevenColumn = new TableColumn<>("");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> eightColumn = new TableColumn<>("");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> nineColumn = new TableColumn<>("Nine");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> tenColumn = new TableColumn<>("Ten");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> elevenColumn = new TableColumn<>("Eleven");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> twelveColumn = new TableColumn<>("Twelve");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> thirteenColumn = new TableColumn<>("Thirteen");
        TableColumn<TableData, String> lastColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last");

        table.setEditable(false);
        table.setPrefWidth(1100);
        table.setMaxWidth(1100);
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(oneColumn, twoColumn, threeColumn, fourColumn, fiveColumn, sixColumn, sevenColumn, eightColumn, nineColumn, tenColumn, elevenColumn, twelveColumn, thirteenColumn, lastColumn);

        table.setFixedCellSize(25.0);

        // This cellValueFactory code could be refactored in the real application
        oneColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("oneColumn"));
        oneColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getOneColumn());
            }
        });
        twoColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("twoColumn"));
        twoColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getTwoColumn());
            }
        });
        threeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("threeColumn"));
        threeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getThreeColumn());
            }
        });
        fourColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("fourColumn"));
        fourColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getFourColumn());
            }
        });
        fiveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("fiveColumn"));
        fiveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getFiveColumn());
            }
        });
        sixColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("sixColumn"));
        sixColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getSixColumn());
            }
        });
        sevenColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("sevenColumn"));
        sevenColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getSevenColumn());
            }
        });
        eightColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("eightColumn"));
        eightColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getEightColumn());
            }
        });
        nineColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("nineColumn"));
        nineColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getNineColumn());
            }
        });
        tenColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("tenColumn"));
        tenColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getTenColumn());
            }
        });
        elevenColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("elevenColumn"));
        elevenColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getElevenColumn());
            }
        });
        twelveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("twelveColumn"));
        twelveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getTwelveColumn());
            }
        });
        thirteenColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("thirteenColumn"));
        thirteenColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getThirteenColumn());
            }
        });
        lastColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("lastColumn"));
        lastColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getLastColumn());
            }
        });

        // using CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY will cause all kinds of odd behaviour because of the autoresize and then the columnWidthListener below.
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        table.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TableData>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends TableData> c) {

                // check to see if any of the data coming in has column 3 or 4 values that columns can be resized with
                if (!columnResizeOperationPerformed) {
                    boolean outerBreak = false;
                    while (c.next() && !outerBreak) {
                        List<? extends TableData> addedSubList = c.getAddedSubList();
                        if (!addedSubList.isEmpty()) {
                            for (TableData data : addedSubList) {
                                outerBreak = checkForColThreeOrFourData(data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                // resize some columns to fit contents, other columns to take up remaining space
                if (!columnResizeOperationPerformed && !table.getItems().isEmpty()) {
                    // only prevent future column resizing if the threeColumn has some valid data to size on
                    if (resizeThreeColumn.length() > 0) {
                        columnResizeOperationPerformed = true;
                    }
                    double totalWidth = 0;
                    totalWidth = autosizeColumn(oneColumn);
                    totalWidth += autosizeColumn(threeColumn);
                    totalWidth += autosizeColumn(fourColumn);
                    totalWidth += autosizeColumn(sixColumn);
                    totalWidth += autosizeColumn(sevenColumn);
                    totalWidth += autosizeColumn(eightColumn);
                    totalWidth += autosizeColumn(nineColumn);
                    totalWidth += autosizeColumn(tenColumn);
                    totalWidth += autosizeColumn(elevenColumn);
                    totalWidth += autosizeColumn(twelveColumn);

                    totalWidth += autosizeColumn(lastColumn);

                    double remainingWidth = table.getWidth() - totalWidth;
                    sizeColumn(twoColumn, remainingWidth / 4.0);
                    sizeColumn(fiveColumn, remainingWidth / 4.0);
                    sizeColumn(thirteenColumn, remainingWidth / 4.0);
                    table.requestLayout();
                }
            }
        });

        ChangeListener<? super Number> columnWidthListener = (obs, ov, nv) -> {

            double totalWidth = table.getColumns().stream()
                    .filter(tc -> !tc.equals(lastColumn))
                    .mapToDouble(TableColumnBase::getWidth)
                    .sum();
            sizeColumn(lastColumn, table.getWidth() - totalWidth);
        };
        // listen for any column resizing or table width changes and assign extra width to the lastColumn above
        table.getColumns().stream()
                .filter(tc -> !tc.equals(lastColumn)).forEach(tc -> {
                    tc.widthProperty().addListener(columnWidthListener);
                });
        table.widthProperty().addListener(columnWidthListener);

        HBox hBox = new HBox(table);
        HBox.setHgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(hBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // create Task to update the table data after the UI is constructed so that the column autoresizing code above is applied as data is populated.
        Task task = new Task() {

            @Override
            protected Object call() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        updateTableData();
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {}
                return null;
            }
        };
        executorService.submit(task);

    }

    /**
     * A test version of a check from the real application to make sure resizing of columns happens when column data of specific columns is valid
     * 
     * @param tableData
     * @return
     */
    private boolean checkForColThreeOrFourData(TableData tableData) {

        if (resizeThreeColumn.length() == 0) {
            resizeThreeColumn = tableData.getThreeColumn();
        }
        if (resizeFourColumn.length() == 0) {
            resizeFourColumn = tableData.getFourColumn();
        }
        if (resizeSixColumn.length() == 0) {
            resizeSixColumn = tableData.getSixColumn();
        }
        if ((resizeThreeColumn.length() > 0) && resizeFourColumn.length() > 0 && resizeSixColumn.length() > 0) { return true; }
        return false;
    }

    public void sizeColumn(TableColumn<?, ?> column, double width) {
        column.setPrefWidth(width);
    }

    public static double autosizeColumn(TableColumn<?, ?> column) {
        final TableView<?> tableView = column.getTableView();
        final Skin<?> skin = tableView.getSkin();
        final int rowsToMeasure = -1;

        try {
            Method method = skin.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("resizeColumnToFitContent", TableColumn.class, int.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(skin, column, rowsToMeasure);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return column.getWidth();
    }


    private void updateTableData() {
        data.setAll(Arrays.asList(new TableData("Manufacturer1", "User 1", "value12345", "desc12345", "defaultName", "17:04:49 15/05/19", "200", "0", "0", "3", "12", "2", "16-15-14", "80"),
                new TableData("Manufacturer2", "User 2", "value67890", "desc67890", "", "17:06:38 15/05/19", "100", "0", "0", "3", "11", "2", "16-15-14", "82")));
    }


    class TableData implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String oneColumn;
        private String twoColumn;
        private String threeColumn;
        private String fourColumn;
        private String fiveColumn;
        private String sixColumn;
        private String sevenColumn;
        private String eightColumn;
        private String nineColumn;
        private String tenColumn;
        private String elevenColumn;
        private String twelveColumn;
        private String thirteenColumn;
        private String lastColumn;

        public TableData(String oneColumn, String twoColumn, String threeColumn, String fourColumn, String fiveColumn, String sixColumn, String sevenColumn, String eightColumn, String nineColumn, String tenColumn, String elevenColumn,
                String twelveColumn, String thirteenColumn, String lastColumn) {
            this.oneColumn = oneColumn;
            this.twoColumn = twoColumn;
            this.threeColumn = threeColumn;
            this.fourColumn = fourColumn;
            this.fiveColumn = fiveColumn;
            this.sixColumn = sixColumn;
            this.sevenColumn = sevenColumn;
            this.eightColumn = eightColumn;
            this.nineColumn = nineColumn;
            this.tenColumn = tenColumn;
            this.elevenColumn = elevenColumn;
            this.twelveColumn = twelveColumn;
            this.thirteenColumn = thirteenColumn;
            this.lastColumn = lastColumn;
        }


        public String getOneColumn() {
            return oneColumn;
        }

        public String getTwoColumn() {
            return twoColumn;
        }

        public String getThreeColumn() {
            return threeColumn;
        }

        public String getFourColumn() {
            return fourColumn;
        }

        public String getFiveColumn() {
            return fiveColumn;
        }

        public String getSixColumn() {
            return sixColumn;
        }

        public String getSevenColumn() {
            return sevenColumn;
        }

        public String getEightColumn() {
            return eightColumn;
        }

        public String getNineColumn() {
            return nineColumn;
        }

        public String getTenColumn() {
            return tenColumn;
        }

        public String getElevenColumn() {
            return elevenColumn;
        }

        public String getTwelveColumn() {
            return twelveColumn;
        }

        public String getThirteenColumn() {
            return thirteenColumn;
        }

        public String getLastColumn() {
            return lastColumn;
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned above this code will auto resize the selected columns and assign the remaining width equally to the other columns.
It will listen to user column width adjustments correctly.
What it won't do is prevent the columns to the right edge vanishing off the view. I would like the right columns to be reduced in width to accomodate the user column width increase in the order described above, right-most first continuing in from the right as columns reach their minimum.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602566/javafx-dynamic-resizing/51616294#51616294) may be similar.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't really what I'm looking for. I want to work with the TableView, TableColumns if possible. I'm going to start looking at either writing some code to deal with the TableColumn resizing I've described or write a custom policy. Any other ideas would be really welcome though?